# Populate Pojo Object using vtd

Tags: java, vtd-xml

I am looking for a smart way to auto-populate my java pojo object with xml data parsed by vtd-xml. I referred this link http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/09/07/schema-less-java-xml-data-binding-with-vtd-xml.html?page=2
But since I am having a very huge pojo object with 100+ fields, assigning each field with fetched value from xml seems quite copy-paste job and cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how you would like the binding to be like? It seems that you have a complex project to start with. No?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author I have a 8mb xml file with nesting of nodes level upto 10 from which I have to sync xml data with database. As of now I have dropped the idea of using VTD and using XML Beans.

Comment: Have you consired using a data integration tool such as Pentaho DI in order to read XML data and sync with DB.

Comment: Actually we want to avoid using tools for keeping the budget low. Informatica was already doing this for us, now we are migrating from informatica to java. I have written custom java code for my requirement and it is working smoothly.